# Pass a dict to scikit learn estimator

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I am trying to pass model parameters as a dict to a Scikit-learn estimator and am having no luck.  It just seems to nest my dict into one of the parameters.  For instance:

```
params = {
 'copy_X': True, 
 'fit_intercept': False, 
 'normalize': True
}

lr = LinearRegression(params)
```

Gives me:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True,
         fit_intercept={'copy_X': True, 'fit_intercept': False,'normalize': True},
     normalize=False)
```

Additionally, I created a function to iterate over the dict and can create a string like:

```
'copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False'
```

This was equally as unsuccessful.  Anyone have any advice here?  The only restriction I have is the data will be coming to me as a dict (well actually a json object being loaded with json.uploads).

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just glad i'm not the only one who wanted to build this lol

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The best solution to initialise your estimator with the right parameters would be to **unpack your dictionary**:

```
lr = LinearRegression(**params)
```

If for some reason you need to set some parameters afterwards, you could use:

```
lr.set_params(**params)
```

This has an advantage over using `setattr` in that it allows Scikit learn to perform some validation checks on the parameters.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer -- it's the standard way to pass a bunch of kwargs to a function.

Answer (score 6):

I got it.  Used setattr like this.

```
for k,v in params.items():
   setattr(lr,k,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

`fit_intercept` is the first argument of the `LinearRegression` object

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

So that explains why your dictionary is being passed to that argument, the other args (also optional) `copy_X` and `normalize` are receiving no parameter so they are using the default values.

You could also do:

```
params = {
 'copy_X': True, 
 'fit_intercept': False, 
 'normalize': True
}

lr = LinearRegression(copy_X = params['copy_X'], \
                      fit_intercept = params['fit_intercept'], \
                      normalize = params['normalize'])
```